# Laravel 5 - Double underscore in query, how to remove one of them

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an issue in Laravel where I have created a new pivot table.  The table is called

```
blog_post_user
```

When I run a query such as:

```
$posts = User::with('blog_user')->get();
```

It returns a `1146 table not found` error.  Looking at the query the issue appears to be that it is converting the table name from:

```
blog_post_user
```

to

```
blog__post_user
```

I suspect this is because of CamelCase, it is taking my name of Blog_Post_User and assuming it to be blog__post_user?

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information about the models you're using, and the relations between them? Is it BlogUser and BlogPost? It seems that for linking users to posts, you'd want a one-to-many relationship rather than many-to-many, which is what a pivot table is for.

Comment: Machavity, you are absolutely right, I am a complete muppet.  I have so much going on between the tables I should have stepped right back and thought more about this rather than focussing on the error itself.    

This question is totally useless, ignore it if you come across it, the relationship is one to many not many to many and therefore no pivot is required.

Answer (score 2):

Check your User model if it is not have protected table variable create Like this

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'blog_post_user';
```

Comment: Whilst this was not related you are right, using the protected $table will ensure that the framework will only use the table name you give it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this today as I also had the 'double underscore' issue like you described. I do need that table (no pivot, regular table) though and think the hint Alupotha gives is maybe not the intended, or at least not the *only* way to tackle the underscore issue, as it seems to be a naming convention thing.

I tinkered and searched around a bit and it looks like the table name is derived from the name of the model as you expected. A CamelCaseModelName leads to a snail_tablename - for this example camel_case_model_name . So when creating the Model for your underscored table make sure not to use both: Camel_CaseTable will lead to a query to the 'no such table' camel__case_table with the double underscore.

Summing up some of the options are:

- Model My_Table will lead to query tablename my__tables (the double
  underscore ..)
- Model MyTable will lead to query tablename my_tables (make sure to
  create the table like this if you want that)
- Mytable will lead to mytable

Means if you want to use my_table as tablename, make sure to use MyTable as model name. Just choose your names aware of that and you will be fine.

Comment: Apologies I thought I had come back and answered this.  As @Alupotha mentioned below set the table name in the model so that it avoids Laravel making assumptions about the table name.